# Apache Rewrite Issue, Custom URI

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, uri

I have a solution but it is one that I know is not the greatest and would better be solved with a full rewrite.  Basically I have 3 rewrites that will go to the correct areas I want and do what they need to do.  However in order to switch between where I need to go I had to write a URI class to strip through the url set the page and vars manually.  It all works out great but the urls are a pain in the ass specially if not formatted exactly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/bsiadmin/$ /bsiadmin/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/bsiadmin/(.+)/$ /bsiadmin/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

So the first rule will make sure to direct everything to the directory and not the root index.php, the second rule does the same if there is a "page" specified.  The last rule will take anything else and make sure it uses the root index.php and goes from there.

Example of urls:

```
http://mysite.test/icecream/id=2/
```

My custom uri class would strip this clean and set id as a $_REQUEST var.

I guess what I really want to know is how can I just rewrite a simple url such as:

```
http://mysite.test?page=icecream&id=2
```

AS

```
http://mysite.test/icecream/id/2/
```

Without any limitation on how many vars can be passed and the directory that does exist "bsiadmin" to display without me having to use a uri class to direct it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite to do so:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*) /$1/$4?$2=$3 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/$ /bsiadmin/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But I think the best would be to use PHP for that job. Because with mod_rewrite you can only rewrite a fixed amount of URL arguments at a time (here one with every rewrite). With PHP you can parse any arbitrary number of arguments like this:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);
if (count($segments) > 2) {
    for ($i=4, $n=count($segments); $i<$n; $i+=2) {
        $_GET[rawurledecode($segments[$i-1])] = rawurldecode($segments[$i]);
    }
    $_GET['page'] = rawurldecode($segments[1]);
}
```

Then all you need for mod_rewrite is this single rule to rewrite the requests to your *index.php*:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^/bsiadmin/index\.php$ /bsiadmin/index.php [L]
```