# mod_rewrite RewriteCond and query string

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, parameters, query-string

recently, I have been working on a small project for a client. I was thinking about using a wordpress style pretty URL format. I googled around a lot and came accross Apache’s mod_rewrite and `RewriteRule`, `RewriteCond`. But didn't find any example which can handle random of parameters. For example:

- `/index.php?param=1` → `/index/param/1`
- `/index.php?foo=bar&hour=1&minutes=12` → `/index/foo/bar/hour/1/minutes/12`
- `/index.php?page=login&attempt=2` → `/index/page/login/attempt/2`

or something similar.

As you can see parameters are not fixed. Is there anyway to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151610

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most CMS does this with PHP.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

**PHP**

```
$URI = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
$URIparts = explode("/", $URI);
```

Then you've got an array of the parts of the url, and you can process them as you want.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` does always exist.

Comment: indeed, i just wanted to write those couple lines very quickly. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks @galambalazs, 

I have modified a little bit so that it only redirect certain pages to it's right controller, this will keep all the parameters.

RewriteRule ^page/?.*$ ./page.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ssl/?.*$ ./ssl.php [L]

Then in PHP

$URI = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
$URIparts = explode("/", $URI);